# External javascript file giving problems

Tags: javascript, html, css, spring

I am new to javascript and working on a small form validation project...I have used external javascript file for this purpose but it is giving me problems.I have included this file properly in my html form but it is not updating any div or changing any color however this file is showing popup alerts.....Another thing is that when I copy and paste the same code directly into my html tags then it works fine......I dont know why this is happening ????
The html tags I have used are actually SPRING HTML tags...Are these tage creating problem????

```
<label for="edit-mail"> First Name<span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span></label> 
<form:input path="firstName" id="firstName" /> 
<div id="firstNameError"</div>   
<form:errors path="firstName"/> 
<div id='user-register_FirstName_errorloc' class="error_strings"></div>
```

Comment: please give more context. Perhaps code samples

Comment: <label for="edit-mail"> First Name<span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span></label> 
        <form:input path="firstName" id="firstName" />
<div id="firstNameError"</div>       <form:errors path="firstName"/>
<div id='user-register_FirstName_errorloc' class="error_strings"></div>

Comment: I want to print this msg document.getElementById("firstNameError").innerHTML = "Firstname connot be empty or greater than 20 letters.";from js file into div id="firstNameError"

Comment: If that is a cut an paste from your code, you are missing the closing '>' on that div

Comment: no actually i missed that here.....its ok in my actual code

Comment: where are you including the javascript and where are you running it? If you run it before load, then it's possible that `firstNameError` isn't in the DOM yet.

Comment: I caught this problem...Actually when i click the submit button,javascript displays the message but it disappears because the whole page reloads.Can you tell me why whole page reloads on pressing submit button ??the code for submit button is here     <input type="submit" name="op" id="edit-submit" value="Next" class="form-submit" onClick="validateForm();">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you're returning `false` to prevent the default behavior of your button (which is to submit the form:

```
<input type="submit" name="op" id="edit-submit" value="Next" class="form-submit" onClick="validateForm();return false;">
```

See the difference here: http://jsfiddle.net/atc3B/